# How to find the sine of an angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to find the sine/cos/tangent/cotangent/cossec/sec of an angle:

In degrees

$\sin(23^{\circ}) =$ ?

In radians

$\sin(0.53) =$ ?

Comment: What is the relationship between $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$? Now given them both, what is $\tan(x)$ and $\cot(x)$? Ditto $\sec(x)$ and $\csc(x)$...

Comment: To understand the relationship between $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, think about a common identity they satisfy.

Comment: Do you want an exact form, or a way to find the result to an arbitrary number of decimal places?  (Taylor expansion *could* help)

Comment: To get the value approximately, note that $23 \approx 22.5 = 45/2$. Since you know all functions of 45 degrees, you can now approximate

Answer (score 1):

In radians you can use the power series of the sine function to get very close to the true value. $$\sin (x) = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^9}{9!}-\frac{x^{11}}{11!}+\cdots$$

The remaining functions have their own power series representations which can be used as well.

Comment: doubt he knows calculus